# api con jquery problemas para retornar (imagenes)

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, api

Estoy tratando de consumir una api con jquery, pero no se si el problema es que el curso que estoy viendo es viejo y ya no se usan las misma sentencias o la api es la que cambio
igual lo trato de abrir usando otra api
Pero tampoco me funciono

Se que hay estructuras y funciones mas simples para estos casos

Pero ustedes me dirán si no vale la pena completar estar sesión, esta forma y manera de código
o como puedo usar jquery para hacerlo mas fácil

creo que esta parte de Apis se puede usar mucho en diferentes sitios
ya voy a completar mi primer curso de desarrollo!

Hola! ya no necesito ayuda la verdad era error de estructura
no se eliminar la pregunta pero dejo el proceso por si alguien lo necesita

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#imagenes").html("");
        var n = $("#nombre").val();
        
        $("#button").click(function(){

            $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",{
            
                tags:n,
                tagmode:"any",
                format:"json"
                
            },function(data){
            
                $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
            
                    $('<img/>').attr("src",item.media.m).appendTo('#imagenes');
                    if(i==3) return false;
                });
            });
        });
    });

</script>

</head>

<body>



    <form>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" />
        <input type="button" id="button"  value="fotos" />

    </form>
        <div id="imagenes"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Puedes responderla debajo y marcar lo que has actualizado, también describir un poco mejor lo ocurrido. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

en el codigo viejo tenia una } demas
esta actualizado arriba!
pero para que quede funcionando bien

se le debe poner estas variables y atributos
dentro  $("#button").click(function(){

var n = $("#nombre").val();

```
        $("#imagenes").empty();
        $("#imagenes").append("<img class='img' src='ajax-loader1.gif'/>");
```

para limpiar la búsqueda y para agregar efecto de carga

un saludo!